# Merge Buffer in a specific location of a File

Tags: c, file, merge, buffer

I've split a file into multiple buffers. 
Now i need to merge all this buffers together to recreate the original file. To do so i need to know how to tell c to copy a specific buffer into a specific position inside the file so that the file gets rebuild as it was.
Is there a method to point at a specific location inside the file.
That way i can just rebuild the file using a the buffer dimension multiplied to the buffer original position and copy it in there.

I can write you an example to be a bit more clear:
The original file is: `"This is an example"`

The first method splits the file into 4 buffers:

```
buf[0] = "This";
buf[1] = " is ";
buf[2] = "an e";
buf[3] = "xamp";
buf[4] = "le  ";
```

Now i need to create a method `merge(char buffer, int position)` that given the position inside the original file, copy this buffer inside the specific spot of the new file.

Thank you in advance. I hope it was clear

Comment: Just write them in order to the file.

Comment: I don't get them in order, i don't have all the buffers at the same time. I just a a buffer at the time, when i receive it. So i know just where it was in the file. I can't store it anywhere else other then the new file

Comment: Then you need to know the size of the file

Comment: I Can manage to get it. But the problem remains, how can i tell c the specific location where to copy the buffer inside the file

Comment: You will need to create a file and fill it with zeros to the known size. Then use `fseek`.